# Why is this claim about limits true

Tags: calculus, analysis

I didn't understand why this claim from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function) is true

> ...More specifically, when $f$ is applied to any input sufficiently close to $p$, the output value is forced arbitrarily close to $L$.

Is not the contrary? we have formally from the definition of limits:

> for *every* $\epsilon>0$ we have one $\delta>0$ such that
>   $0<|x-p|<\delta\implies |f(x)-L| < \epsilon$.

So I think, the best claim is

> ... More specifically, any output sufficiently close to $L$, the input
>   value is forced arbitrarily close to $p$.

So my question is why the wikipedia claim is true?

Comment: Read the implication carefully: if $0 < |x-p| < \delta$ then $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$. If the input is close to $p$, then the output is close to $L$.

Comment: Your claim is not generally true.  Consider a constant function $f(x)$. In that case, even specifying the output exactly in no way restricts the input.

Comment: The wiki sentence is not fantastically clear but it is essentially correct. We certainly don't have "the contrary" as you suggest. Consider just reordering it: "More specifically, the output value is forced arbitrarily close to $L$ when $f$ is applied to any input sufficiently close to $p$."

Answer (score 3):

The original claim is correct. Let's take a look at an example $f(x)=\sin x, p=0, L=0$. If you take any $\varepsilon$ and take your $x$ really close to $p$ ($|x|<\varepsilon$ is enough, but it's not important), then you will get that $\sin x$ is really close to $L$.

But your modified claim is not correct. We can be as close to $L$ as we like without $x$ being close to $p$. For example, we can have $x=2\pi$. Then $\sin x$ is in fact equal to $L$, but $x$ is not close to $p$.

Comment: I'm confused. In the definition of limit you have to choice the $\epsilon$ first (as you have done). According to wikipedia's definition we have a tendency to think we have to choose $\delta$ first.

Answer (score 1):

Definition of limits, it words:

"If $x$ is close to $p$, then $f$ is close to $L$."

Now, $x$ is *the input to the function*, so I'll replace occurrences of $x$ with those words:

"If the input to the function is close to $p$, then $f$ is close to $L$."

Now, $f$ is *the output of the function*, so I'll replace those words:

"If the input to the function is close to $p$, then the output of the function is close to $L$."

The Wikipedia sentence is not that great, but it is basically correct.

Comment: That's what I didn't understand. we first choose an arbitrarily $\epsilon$. Following your first claim we have a tendency to think that we have to first choose $\delta$. Did you follow my doubt?

Comment: In the definition, you wrote "we have one $\delta$...". That means it exists, regardless of weather we choose it or not. There is at least one $\delta$ and a bunch of $\epsilon$ values such that closeness in input implies closeness in output. The order of "choosing" an $\epsilon$ or $\delta$ is pretty unimportant.

Comment: Makes sense, this was basically my doubt, I was confused about the order of choice of this constants. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> for *every* $\varepsilon>0$ we have one $\delta>0$ such that
>   $0<|x-p|<\delta\implies |f(x)-L| < \varepsilon$.

The phrase $\text{“ } 0<|x-p|<\delta \Longrightarrow |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon \text{ ''}  $ says if $x$ is close to $p$ then $f(x)$ is close to $L$.

The phrase $\text{“ For every } \varepsilon>0, \text{ there exists } \delta>0\ \cdots\cdots \text{ ''}$ starts with $\varepsilon$, which measures distances in the space where $f(x)$ and $L$ live, and goes on to $\delta$, which measures distances in the space where $x$ and $p$ live, and I suspect that is the cause of your confusion.

What it's saying is that no matter how close you want to make $f(x)$ to $L$ (i.e. no matter how small $\varepsilon$ is), you can do it by making $x$ close enough to $p$ (i.e. by making $\delta$ small enough).  Thus making $x$ close to $p$ makes $f(x)$ close to $L$.

With $f(x)=x^2$, you have $\lim\limits_{x\to3} f(x)=9$.  But making $f(x)$ close to $9$ is no guarantee that $x$ is close to $3$, since $x$ could be close to $-3$.